# Need Improvement on Script Which Continuously Tests Website

Tags: shell-script, networking, scripting, ping, bourne-shell

Need improvement on a script which continuously tests website.

It's currently been used the following script, but it is giving a large amount of failing emails, while website is still up:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    date > wsdown.txt ;
    cp /dev/null pingop.txt ;
    ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 website.com > pingop.txt ;
    sleep 1 ;
    if grep -q "64 bytes" pingop.txt ; then
        :
    else
        mutt -s "Website Down!" bruno.bvaraujo@gmail.com < wsdown.txt ;
        sleep 10 ;
    fi
done
```

Thinking now or in somehow improving this script or using another way.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that you're testing a website with ping; perhaps ICMP (ping) is occasionally being blocked or dropped? Consider testing instead against the web server port?

Comment: You might have better results using httping. It initiates an actual HTTP(S) connection to the server _and_ verifies that the response is successful (2xx). https://www.vanheusden.com/httping/

Comment: Is this the only website you'll ever monitor?  It may be worth exploring a more general purpose alerting system, like Check_MK or similar.

Comment: What is `Check_MK`? An application, is it in Linux Standard Base?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need `;` at the end of each line, this is not C.

You don't need:

```
cp /dev/null pingop.txt
```

because the very next line in the script

```
ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 google.com > pingop.txt
```

will overwrite contents of `pingop.txt` anyway. And if we're here, you
don't even need to save output of `ping` to the file if you're not
going to send it or process it later, just do:

```
if ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 website.com >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    sleep 1
else
    mutt -s "Website Down!" bruno.bvaraujo@gmail.com < wsdown.txt
    sleep 10
```

To answer your question about false alarms - `ping` might not be the
best way for testing if website is up.  Some websites just do not
respond to ICMP requests, for example:

```
$ ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 httpbin.org
PING httpbin.org (3.222.220.121) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- httpbin.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

However, `http://httpbin.org` is up. If you're using `website.com` in
your example you most probably access it with HTTP/HTTPS and in that
case consider using `curl -Is`:

```
$ curl -Is "httpbin.org" >/dev/null  2>&1
$ echo $?
0
$ curl -Is "non-existing-domain-lalalala.com" >/dev/null  2>&1
$ echo $?
6
```

OP asked about speed difference between `ping` and `curl` in the
comments.  There is no big difference if you're testing website that
responds to `ping`:

```
$ time curl -Is google.com >/dev/null  2>&1
real    0m0.068s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.001s
$ time ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 google.com
PING google.com (216.58.215.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from waw02s17-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.215.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=8.06 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.068/8.068/8.068/0.000 ms
real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

But when testing website that does not respond to `ping` then `curl`
is not only more reliable but also faster than ping with `-W` that you
use now:

```
$ time ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 httpbin.org
PING httpbin.org (3.222.220.121) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- httpbin.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms


real    0m1.020s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time curl -Is httpbin.org  >/dev/null  2>&1

real    0m0.256s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: I would get log from curl/wget transfert and parse for 20x http's answer versus 404/50x. Latter answer can be send as warning mail.

Comment: Good idea. I wonder however how should `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`  be treated?

Comment: For example `curl -Is shellhacks.com`

Comment: do we speak about Schrodinger sites ? neither up, nor down ? you can't tell unless you log to server.

Comment: `https://www.shellhacks.com` is up.

Comment: OK, it says 200 with `curl -Is "https://www.shellhacks.com"`.

Comment: I would follow redirects as clients would do. You could follow redirects with `-L` and print the http status with `-w "%{http_code}"` like `curl -IsL -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://google.com`.

Comment: We are thinking in real time response in case of site down, as quickly as possible. Would `curl` be faster and more precise than `ping`?

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914 Not necessarily faster, but you don't have any benefit if the webserver is down or serves a 503 and the ping is ok.

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914: I updated my answer

Comment: Would you know the amount of data used in this `curl` test?

The `ping` itself uses about 56(84) bytes.

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914: you can measure it with something like `curl -w "%{size_header}\n" -Is google.com`

Comment: `httping -q -c1 -t1 -s https://example.com` and check the exit code. By default it only considers 200 to be success, but you can add whichever codes you want to the success check with `-o`.

Answer (score 3):

there is not much to improve for a **ping** version

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    date > wsdown.txt  
    ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 website.com > pingop.txt # '>' will overwrite file
    sleep 1 ;
    if ! grep -q "64 bytes" pingop.txt ; then ## negate test
        mutt -s "Website Down!" bruno.bvaraujo@gmail.com < wsdown.txt 
        sleep 10 
    fi
done
```

note that

- you din't need `;` to "close" command
- in case `website.com` goes down, you are likely to get a lot of spam
- ping(icmp) and http:// are two different protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the `ping` command timing, it would increase the time response, but it would maybe also reduce losses, as follows:

From `ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 website.com > pingop.txt ;`

To `ping -i 2 -c 1 -W 4 website.com > pingop.txt ;`